# Cedilla does not work under Softmaker Office

Tags: manjaro, unicode, gtk, qt

Infos [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/hVVZ3dWz2B/) Cedilla works in all other apps but SoftMaker office where it delivers a ć. What might I be missing? This might be some QT/GTK issue but I'm not sure about how to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just edit:

```
/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose
```

Replace all occurrences of "ć" with "ç". Save and restart Softmaker Office.